# Find every arrangement of an array element in mysql regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

There is a table with a `tag` column that has different tags separated by a `,` like below:

```
| id | tag   |
| -- | ----- |
| 1  | a,b,c |
| 2  | b,a,h |
| 3  | c,g,e |
```

How can I select every rows that has for example `a` and `b` in their tag column.

I am using **REGEX** in **MySQL**, the problem is when the position of tags changes (ie: `a,b` and `b,a`), I cannot get all rows with the desired tags.

Here is the query to get both `a` and `b` tags:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE tag REGEXP 'b.*a'
```

I am seeking for a regex that is indifferent to the position of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a couple of [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) calls would be easier than a regex:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sample_table
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('a', tag) > 0 AND
       FIND_IN_SET('b', tag) > 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't help me sir. Searching for `a` and `b` is just an example, I have to do a filter keys on different categories based on this *tag* and using regex is mandatory for me.

Answer (score 0):

And please read also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `tag` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `tag`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'a,b,c'),
>   ('2', 'b,a,h'),
>   ('3', 'c,g,e');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm table1 WHERE tag REGEXP 'a+.*,b+' OR tag REGEXP 'b+.*,a+'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | tag  
> -: | :----
>  1 | a,b,c
>  2 | b,a,h
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm table1 WHERE tag REGEXP '(a+.*,b+|b+.*,a+)'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | tag  
> -: | :----
>  1 | a,b,c
>  2 | b,a,h
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fad273651a69659636020b6bdeaf697f)*

To address you other, you make a string, with all posible poattern [a,b,b,c,d,e,f] Give it to a stored procedure,
Split that thingl and than makle a huge where clause

This is basically text `CONCAT("tag REGEXP '", pattern1,"+.*,",pattern2,"+' OR tag REGEXP '",pattern2,"+.*,",pqattern1,"'")`

and so you replace a nd b with an element fro  the string.

That will take some programming, but better that writing so may patter by hand

Comment: Considering this solution, I have to make different possibilities of `ab`. For example if I have `a,b,c,d,e,f`. I guess I have to make `2^6` different possibilities to get the desired result. Am I right?

Comment: it is the question, if you can find a pattern, for your wanted search, like i did. basically more complicate it gets more you have to know regex, so look here to normalize the table and do a "normal" sql search, that will be complicated as well, but regex is somewhat strange to handle

Comment: I know that the structure of the table is a nightmare, but I am editing an old project which is online I have to make this filter on it. I appreciate it if you help me on the regex

Comment: This is matching `aaa, aaa`, no `b` here!